# Python kill defunct child process itself

Tags: python, multiprocessing, defunct

I'm using multiprocessing python lib.
I create new Process and executing my job.
After finishing job, I just call exit(0), but process is 'defunct' state.
I try to kill as 'kill -9 PID', 'kill -18 PID' and etc, but I can't kill child process with keep parent process live.

How should I do? This is my python code

'process.py'

```
def process(data, id):
    while isWorking:
        #work process and change isWorking to False

process = Process(target=process, args=(data,id))
process.start()
```

it's my process list (ps -al)

```
0 S  1001 19295 19291  0  80   0 - 45817 poll_s pts/3    00:00:09 python3
1 Z  1001 19339 19295  3  80   0 -     0 -      pts/3    00:00:58 pyth <defunct>
```

I want to keep live parent process(19295) and kill child defunct process 19339.
How should I doe?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
pkill -9 python

ps -ef|grep python
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: no I just want keep live parent python process and only kill child python process.